# What is the correct URI to call controller in web api in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

**my controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

namespace WebAPIDemo.Controllers
{
    public class WebAPIDemoController : ApiController
    {           
        public class Users
        {
            string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();
            MySqlDataReader reader = null;
            MySqlConnection connection;

            public int Id;
            public string FirstName;

            [ActionName("GetUser")]
            [Route("api/WebAPIDemo/GetUserById")]

            [HttpGet]
            public Users GetUserById(int UserId)
            {       
                using (connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
                {     
                    MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand();
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select * from User where id='"+ UserId + "' ";
                    sqlCmd.Connection = connection;
                    connection.Open();
                    reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                    Users usr = new Users();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {    
                        usr.FirstName = (Convert.IsDBNull(reader["FirstName"]) ? "" : Convert.ToString(reader["FirstName"]));
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                    return usr;                    
                 }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

**web api config route**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace WebAPIDemo
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
            //config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            //config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();



            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**URI**

http://localhost:53869/api/WebAPIDemo/GetUserById?id=96

**Error message**

```
<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:53869/api/WebAPIDemo/GetUserById?id=96'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No action was found on the controller 'WebAPIDemo' that matches the request.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

I m new to web api ..
Can some body help...
i cant find what is the error...
i have read some articles from google but cant solve .......

Comment: thanks rboe..... but even after moving the method inside WebAPIDemoController...still there is error....

Comment: Either update the query string to `?UserId=96` or change the action parameter to `id`. They need to match in order for the route to match.

Comment: Put `[Route("~")]` on top of your controller please.

Answer (score 0):

Your action method is not inside the controller; it is inside the class `Users`. Move it one level up, then it should be found (has to be a method of `WebAPIDemoController`). For this example I have extracted the `Users` class from the controller.

```
public class Users
{        
    public int Id;
    public string FirstName;
}

public class WebAPIDemoController : ApiController
{               
    [ActionName("GetUser")]
    [Route("api/WebAPIDemo/GetUserById")]

    [HttpGet]
    public Users GetUserById(int UserId)
    {       
        string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();
        MySqlDataReader reader = null;
        MySqlConnection connection;

        using (connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {     
            MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand();
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select * from User where id='"+ UserId + "' ";
            sqlCmd.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            Users usr = new Users();
            while (reader.Read())
            {    
                usr.FirstName = (Convert.IsDBNull(reader["FirstName"]) ? "" : Convert.ToString(reader["FirstName"]));
                connection.Close();
            }
            return usr;                                     
        }    
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying separations of concerns (Soc) and Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) to your example you need to break up your classes so that they are not responsible for too many things.

Break your User (model) class out into its own class

```
public class User {
    public int Id;
    public string FirstName;
}
```

Extract the Data Access into its own class.

```
public class UsersContext {
    string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();

    public User GetUserById(int UserId) {
        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring)) {
            using (var command = new MySqlCommand()) {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.CommandText = "Select * from User where id='@UserId'";
                command.Connection = connection;

                var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
                parameter.ParameterName = "@UserId";
                parameter.Value = UserId;

                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

                connection.Open();
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
                    var user = new User();
                    while (reader.Read()) {
                        user.FirstName = (Convert.IsDBNull(reader["FirstName"]) ? "" : Convert.ToString(reader["FirstName"]));
                    }
                    return user;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which then leaves your **ApiController** to focus on handling the request

```
public class WebAPIDemoController : ApiController {

    [ActionName("GetUser")]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/WebAPIDemo/GetUserById")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUserById(int id) {
        var context = new UsersContext();

        var user = context.GetUserById(id);

        return Ok(user);
    }
}
```

In order to allow the following request

```
http://localhost:53869/api/WebAPIDemo/GetUserById?id=96
```

to be matched by the routing engine you need to make sure that the parameters match. In your example your call with query string `?id=96` but in your action you have

```
GetUserById(int UserId) { ... }
```

Either update the query string to `?UserId=96` or change the action parameter to

```
GetUserById(int id) { ... }
```

in the **ApiController**. They need to match in order for the route to match them when requests are made.